# Is it possible to use absolute or external URL in Angular 4/5/6 components?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-components, angular6

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-metatags',
  templateUrl: 'https://example.com/index.html',
  styleUrls: ['./metatags.component.css']
})
```

Is it possible in Angular 4/5/6 to use an external HTML file as template URL?